# How to make a grouped barchart with two groups on x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data that looks like this

```
Name, Clusters, incorrectly_classified
PCA, 2, 34.37
PCA, 6, 60.80
ICA2, 2, 37.89
ICA6, 2, 33.20
ICA2, 6, 69.66
ICA6, 6, 60.54
RP2, 2, 32.94
RP4, 2, 33.59
RP6, 2, 31.25
RP2, 6, 68.75
RP4, 6, 61.58
RP6, 6, 56.77
```

I would like to create a barplot for the above data that is similar to this plot I drew

x axis will have two numbers 2 or 6. Y-axis will have `incorrectly_classified` and the `Name` will be plotted for each `2` or `6`. Each Name for each group (2 or 6) would be colored consistently among the two groups.

Is this possible to achieve with barchart? If not with barchart, then what is a good way to plot this data
[image]

Comment: This is possible with ggplot and geom_bar. I can post a solution, but I need a little more info. The y-axis will be "incorrectly_classified" values, but how do you want those values combined? For example the third to last and last rows have the same name and same cluster, so how do you want the two values (65.49 and 56.64) combined? Sum? Mean?

Comment: @jwilley44 you can ignore the ones with the same name and same cluster. I've edited the question and removed those rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following is what you are after.

```
ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = factor(Clusters), y = incorrectly_classified, fill = Name)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
labs(x = "Clusters", y = "Incorrectly classified")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome that looks great! Also, awesome flight map in your profile!

Comment: @birdy Thanks for your comment. I am glad that this helped you. Thanks for your comment for the flight map as well!

Comment: i worked my answer out in other answer with barplot() wich comes with R , but I agree that ggplot is also for this the better option

Comment: @jebsel If you can use base R for graphics, I think that is a plus.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with barplot.

An example:

```
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
  xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
    legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

**EDIT**

I will also work my answer out to demonstrate the barplot option (although ggplot is much cooler :-) ):

if df is your dataframe:

```
dfwide<-reshape(df,timevar="Clusters",v.names="incorrectly_classified",idvar="Name",direction="wide")
rownames(dfwide) <- dfwide$Name
dfwide$Name<-NULL
names(dfwide)[names(dfwide)=="incorrectly_classified.2"] <- "2"
names(dfwide)[names(dfwide)=="incorrectly_classified.6"] <- "6"

dfwide<-as.matrix(dfwide)

barplot(dfwide, main="Your Graph",
        xlab="Clusters",ylab="incorrectly_classified",col=c("darkblue","red","orange","green","purple","grey"),
        legend = rownames(dfwide), beside=TRUE,args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty = "n", inset=c(0.15, -0.15)))
```

[image]